# Trying to write a function that searches for a few different values in each row and outputs a match count as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have a DataFrame

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['cam1','cam2','cam1','cam4'],'B':['cam2', 'cam1', 'cam4', 'cam3'],'C':['cam3','cam4', 'cam5','cam2']})
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | cam1 | cam2 | cam3 |
| 1 | cam2 | cam1 | cam4 |
| 2 | cam1 | cam4 | cam5 |
| 3 | cam4 | cam3 | cam2 |

I'd like to add a column that counts the amount of times 'cam1' or 'cam2' appears in each row.

The desired output would look like this:

|  | A | B | C | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | cam1 | cam2 | cam3 | 2 |
| 1 | cam2 | cam1 | cam4 | 2 |
| 2 | cam1 | cam4 | cam5 | 1 |
| 3 | cam4 | cam3 | cam2 | 1 |

Is there a way to do this without using a million if else statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.aggregate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) with two lambda functions to achieve what you're describing:

```
df["Count"] = df.aggregate(lambda x: len(list(filter(lambda y: y in ["cam1", "cam2"], x.values))), axis="columns")
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/IntelligentCooperativeApplet#main.py)</sup>

---

Per the comment - the desire to individually "weight" specific values could be achieved by changing up the paradigm slightly to map each value to a numerical value and then `sum`ming the resulting iterable:

```
df["Count"] = df.aggregate(lambda x: sum(list(map(lambda y: 2 if y ==  "cam1" else (1 if y == "cam2" else 0), x.values))), axis="columns")
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/IntelligentCooperativeApplet-1#main.py)</sup>

If in this scenario there are more than just a few values to map against their weights, you may consider doing this more eloquently with a `dict`:

```
weights = {
  "cam1": 2,
  "cam2": 1
}

df["Count"] = df.aggregate(lambda x: sum(list(map(lambda y: weights[y] if y in weights else 0, x.values))), axis="columns")
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/IntelligentCooperativeApplet-2#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer @esqew, would there be anyway to add a weight to "cam1" so that when it is counted it counts for 2 instead of just 1?

Comment: @pythonTyler You could, but it would look slightly different than the one I've posted here. Check my edit -  instead of using the `len` of a `filter`ed list, you would `sum` the result of `map`ping against the desired values. The practicality of this depends on your specific requirements and how many of these conditions you'd have.